# Trying to call oracle function from dotnet getting error while returning value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, ado.net

I'm trying to call a oracle function from asp.net mvc side and returning a value but getting error "{"ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small\nORA-06512: at line 1"}.

In oracle side i have written a function which return concatenated value and then in dotnet side i am retrieving that value.

Oracle function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_multi_val(PROD_DATE in varchar2)
 RETURN varchar2  
 is 
  var_value varchar2(200);
  x varchar2     (200);
  cursor age_val is 
 SELECT AGE_CD,
 decode(AGE_CD,'04','CL LINE(R','05','CR ','A',NULL,STAGE_DESC) STAGE_DESC ,
 STAGE_SEQ      
 FROM DBPROD.PROD_AGE_MST
 WHERE STAGE_SEQ < 15
 AND STAGE_CD NOT IN ('ZA','05')
 ORDER BY 3;  
 BEGIN
    FOR i IN age_val LOOP
      SELECT To_Char(Round(NVL(SUM(NVL(WF_PROD_WT, 0)), 0), 0)) 
      INTO X
      FROM DBPROD.Prod_age_wp_gs_cur
     WHERE WF_DATE BETWEEN trunc(to_date(PROD_DATE,'dd-MM-YYYY')) AND  trunc(to_date(OD_DATE,'dd-MM-YYYY')+1)
       AND WF_STAGE_CD=i.AGE_CD;
    var_value := var_value || X||'~';
   END LOOP;
return var_value;
END;
```

Asp.net MVC

```
try
   {
    conn.Open();
    OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand();
    command.Connection = conn;
    command.CommandText = "func_multi_val";
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.Add("PROD_DATE", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
    command.Parameters.Add("var_value", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
    command.ExecuteScalar();
    object o = command.ExecuteScalar();

     }  
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
     }
```

Expected:Concatenated value should be return from oracle side retrieve at dotnet.
Actual:Getting error at dotnet side while binding "{"ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small\nORA-06512: at line 1"}".Any idea would appreciated

Comment: start with passing prod_date as a date from .NET DateTime, then check parameter binding order and varchar2 sizes.

Comment: `var_value varchar2(200);` --> `var_value varchar2(32000);`

Comment: @Tejash----ORA-00980 it wont work getting same error again

Comment: `x varchar2     (200);` --> `x varchar2     (4000);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternate way for answer i just Remove parameter from oracle query and use sysdate function instead of using PROD_DATE  variable

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_multi_val
 RETURN varchar2  
 is 
  var_value varchar2(200);
  x varchar2     (200);
  cursor age_val is 
 SELECT AGE_CD,
 decode(AGE_CD,'04','CL LINE(R','05','CR ','A',NULL,STAGE_DESC) STAGE_DESC ,
 STAGE_SEQ      
 FROM DBPROD.PROD_AGE_MST
 WHERE STAGE_SEQ < 15
 AND STAGE_CD NOT IN ('ZA','05')
 ORDER BY 3;  
 BEGIN
    FOR i IN age_val LOOP
      SELECT To_Char(Round(NVL(SUM(NVL(WF_PROD_WT, 0)), 0), 0)) 
      INTO X
      FROM DBPROD.Prod_age_wp_gs_cur
     WHERE PSWF_DATE BETWEEN sysdate AND  sysdate+1
       AND WF_STAGE_CD=i.AGE_CD;
    var_value := var_value || X||'~';
   END LOOP;
return var_value;
END;
```

and in dotnet side i do the following modification

```
try
   {
    conn.Open();
    OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand();
    command.Connection = conn;
    command.CommandText = "func_multi_val";
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;    
   command.Parameters.Add("var_value", OracleDbType.Varchar2,200).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
    command.ExecuteScalar();
    object o = command.Parameters["var_value"].Value;

     }  
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
     }
```

Comment: using data length "200" in dot net side at "OracleDbType.Varchar2,200" fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

`VAR_VALUE` contains concatenated result. If it (the result) is longer than 200 characters, it can't fit into `VARCHAR2(200)` variable, as `VAR_VALUE` is declared as such.

Therefore, enlarge it.

Comment: ORA-06502 is an error raised on Oracle side, so ... think & test it over.

Comment: i changed the VAR_VALUE datatype to clob but now getting error {"ORA-22275: invalid LOB locator specified\nORA-06512: at line 1"}

Comment: Why CLOB? Do you really expect something *that large*? Try with `VARCHAR2(32767)`.

Comment: still getting same error {"ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small\nORA-06512: at line 1"}

Comment: OK. Just to make sure that VAR_VALUE's size is a culprit: instead of `var_value := var_value || X||'~';`, put `var_value := substr(var_value || X||'~', 1, 1000);` which will shorten it to 1000 characters. Disregard the fact that it maybe/probably won't contain the full string length.

Comment: still getting error {"ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small\nORA-06512: at line 1"} on using substring

Comment: What is VAR_VALUE declared as now? Should have remained VARCHAR2(32767).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196916/discussion-between-mohan-and-littlefoot).